# How to conditionally render a specific JSX element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose the following:

```
import * as React from 'react';

const isMobile = true;

const App = () => {
    const swipeStart = React.useCallback(() => {}, []);
    const swipeMove = React.useCallback(() => {}, []);

    const Component = isMobile
        ? <div onTouchStart={swipeStart} onTouchMove={swipeMove}  />
        : <React.Fragment />;

    return (
        <Component>
            <span>child</span>
        </Component>
    );
}
```

How can I get this to work? I know that with styled-components or @emotion, there is an [as](https://emotion.sh/docs/styled#as-prop) prop, but I don't want to install more libraries than necessary.

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: Typescript throws an error `JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `Component` into a component, currently its something called Component that contains some JSX.

eg.
`const X = <div/>`  <- JSX

`const X = (p) => <div/>`  <- Component

eg.

```js
const { useState, useCallback } = React;

const isMobile = true;

const App = () => {
    const swipeStart = React.useCallback(() => {}, []);
    const swipeMove = React.useCallback(() => {}, []);

    const Component = (p) => isMobile
        ? <div onTouchStart={swipeStart} onTouchMove={swipeMove} {...p}/>
        : <React.Fragment {...p}/>;

    return (
        <Component>
            <span>child</span>
        </Component>
    );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Note: `{...p}` is just a way of passing all the props, the main one in your case is `children`.

Also seen as you mentioned Typescript, to keep Typescript happy you could just do ->

`const Component = (p: {children:React.ReactNode} )  => isMobile`

Also one issue with this, even if you have `isMobile` set to false, it's going to create 2 useCallback's that never get used.  To get around this you could split this up.

eg.

```
const isMobile = true;

const Component = isMobile
    ? (props:{children:React.ReactNode}) => {
        const swipeStart = React.useCallback(() => {}, []);
        const swipeMove = React.useCallback(() => {}, []);
        return <div onTouchStart={swipeStart} onTouchMove={swipeMove} {...props}/>
    }
    : (props:{children:React.ReactNode}) => <React.Fragment {...props}/>
    

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Component>
            <span>child</span>
        </Component>
    );
}
```

In above if you set `isMobile` to false, `useCallback` is then never even used.

Answer (score 2):

It's easies to assign `Component` to just the type of element.

Then pass the props to the `Component`.

Since `React.Fragment` won't do anything with those props it gets the desired behaviour.

(an if / else with return would also work)

```js
const { useState, useCallback } = React;

const isMobile = true;

const App = () => {
    const swipeStart = React.useCallback(() => {}, []);
    const swipeMove = React.useCallback(() => {}, []);

    const Component = isMobile ? 'div' : React.Fragment;
    
    return (
        <Component onTouchStart={swipeStart} onTouchMove={swipeMove}>
            <span>child</span>
        </Component>
    );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

---

Should you don't want to pass the props if it's not needed.

Another option is to make an empty object, and only add the props if `isMobile`. Then spread (`...`) the object to `Component`

```js
const { useState, useCallback } = React;

const isMobile = true;

const App = () => {

    const props = {};
    if (isMobile) {
        props.onTouchStart = React.useCallback(() => {}, []);;
        props.onTouchMove = React.useCallback(() => {}, []);;
    }
    
    const Component = isMobile ? 'div' : React.Fragment;
    
    return (
        <Component {...props}>
            <span>child</span>
        </Component>
    );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here are good, but just to round out the options . . . another approach is to put the *contents* into a variable so that you can reference them across both the mobile and non-mobile codepaths:

```
import * as React from 'react';

const isMobile = true;

const App = () => {
    const swipeStart = React.useCallback(() => {}, []);
    const swipeMove = React.useCallback(() => {}, []);

    const componentContents = <span>child</span>;

    if (isMobile) {
        return (
            <div onTouchStart={swipeStart} onTouchMove={swipeMove}>
                {contents}
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        return contents;
    }
}
```