# react isLoading state not behaving correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, conditional-statements

I am trying to make a skeleton loading effect when isLoading state is true (its set to true on init), like this =>

```
{isLoading  ? (
            <div className="grid grid-cols-4 gap-3">
              {voiceData.voices.map((voice) => (
                <Skeleton key={voice.voice_id} className="w-[200px] h-[250px] rounded-md" />
              ))}
          </div>
          ) : <div id="dash-card-container" className="grid grid-cols-4 gap-3" >
                {voiceData.voices.map((voice) => (
                  <VoiceCard onClick={() => {
                    // Store the voice object in localStorage
                    localStorage.setItem("voice", JSON.stringify(voice));
                    console.log(localStorage.getItem("voice"));
                    // Navigate to the editor route
                    navigate("/create/editor");
                  }} key={voice.voice_id} img={voice.img} name={voice.name} category={voice.category} />
                ))}
            </div>
    }
```

But for some reason it's not working when I reload the page, here is my useEffect for calling the api

```
// Fetching voices from api
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchVoices = async () => {
      // async function to fetch voices
      try {
        setIsLoading(true);

        const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/voices");
        const data = response.data;
        
        console.log("data:", data);
        setVoiceData(data);
        console.log("Voicedata fetched:", voiceData)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching voices", error)
        setIsLoading(false)
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchVoices();
  }, []);
```

I've tried to  removing the "finally" block but this did not do it either

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchVoices = async () => {
      // async function to fetch voices
      try {
        setIsLoading(true);

        const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/voices");
        const data = response.data;
        
        console.log("data:", data);
        setVoiceData(data);
        console.log("Voicedata fetched:", voiceData)
        setIsLoading(false)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching voices", error)
        setIsLoading(false)
      } 
    };
    fetchVoices();
  }, []);
```

I know my loading effect is working because if I never set setIsLoading => false it shows up.[image]

I've also tried console.logging both at the beginning of the try block where I set it to true and at the end where I set it to false and it's the same value every time, either true or false, but this has no impact on rendering which I find weird.

I'm a bit new to this but I don't think I have missed anything major. Any help would be greatly appriciated as I've banged my head for a while now.

Edit: Another thing I might add, the loading effect works when pressing control + s which re-renders the page but not clicking the actual reload button.

Comment: Your `useEffect`  -> `}, []);`  has no dependencies, so that means on any state change it's going to run again, so you have created an infinite loop.

Comment: If the useEffect has an empty array as dependency it will run only on the initial render.. could you set up a codesandbox and reproduce the issue there? At the first glance there seems to be no issue with this code

Comment: Can you share your full file as it could be something else leading to the issue

Comment: @Keith Any idea what I should put as a dependency?

Comment: @David is correct here, an empty array should be only mount once anyway, so forget what I said there.   To really help if you could knock up a snippet here on SO, for an example of running React in SO, here is one I created recently https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77579061/how-to-conditionally-render-a-specific-jsx-element/77579287#77579287  You might need to mock the `axios.get` etc, but it should be possible to show your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can move `fetchVoices` outside of the `useEffect` and include a [useCallback hook](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback). Also, check to see if your API request was successful before mutating `isLoading` as so:

```
  const fetchVoices = useCallback(async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/voices");
      const data = response.data;

      setIsLoading(false);
      console.log("data:", data);
      setVoiceData(data);

      console.log("Voicedata fetched:", data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching voices", error);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchVoices();
  }, [fetchVoices]);
```

Comment: This did not work for me sadly :(

Comment: I have modified the answer